# Logical Effort (G) and Effort (H) in Parallel

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

I am struggling with this question in which I need to understand what is the route with the least effort (H).
Usually, I'm given a route but it's very simple to calculate, because all the other inputs of the logical gates are regular inputs without any logical gates connected to them, like in this example:

[image]

The main difference and what I am struggling with, is in the example above the route is clear, and the legs of the logical gates are just regular inputs..

The circuit which I need to analyze is this:

[image]

And the question is **which route has the least effort (H) - A,C, or they both the same.**

My hunch is that they're both the same, but I can't figure out how to calculate it.
I think the fan-out (f) is the same for both routes - 4/1=4 (I might be wrong here so please let me know if I do).
But I'm not sure how to calculate the logical effort (G) in the routes.

For example, if I look at route A, so the first logic gate is a NOT (g=1), and the next one is NAND2 (g=4/3), but, the other input of the NAND also has a NOT gate connected to it. In my opinion, this shouldn't matter (because again, g of NOT is 1). But when I look further to this route I have a XOR2 (g=4). so far, G=g1xg2xg3=1x4/3x4=16/3, and H=GxF=64/3.
But I don't think it's right, since the other input of the XOR2 is connected to route C, so it has a NOR and a NOT beforehand.

So finally - my question is how do you calculate the effort of a route, if it has more logical gates from the other input?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you please link to where you are getting these definitions of effort (H) and logical effort(G)?

Comment: And what purpose do capacitors serve in your schematic?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_effort , and I assume that the capacitors represents the capacitance of the CMOS transistors which make the logic gates.. I am now almost certain you shouldn't take in consideration the path going backwards (like I thought), Thus route A should have the least effort... The definition in Wiki might be different in names, but have the same meaning

Comment: 1) check your exercise schematic, typically external capacitors don't belong here. 2) the whole point of the LE technique is a factorization of propagation delay: delaytime = d·tau, d = f + p, f = g·h, etc. Read carefully the wiki article, and search and read a treasure trove of course notes and presentations that are hosted on EE schools's websites. 3) power transistors have gate capacitances on the order of nanofarads at most; VLSI MOSFET transistors' gate capacitances are measured in picofarads and even femtofarads. The interconnects have comparable capacitances